# API - Create a contact from an external site

Tags: api, rest

I have the need to create/update a contact from an external site.
If I understand correctly, the only way to do this is to use Rest API. In my test I had no problem to read the database, but when using the "create" action, as in the following PHP code:

> $url='http://.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=create&api_key=...&key=...&json={"sequential":1,"first_name":"Gianni","last_name":"Predan"}';
>
> $responsestr = file_get_contents($url);

I obtain the error "*All requests that modify the database must be http POST, not GET.*"

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is "How do I send a POST request with PHP?". See the following stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php .

Comment: Thank Kainuk, in Itaky we says "I was lost in a glass of water"